# Getting a list of values from dictionary when values are tuples within lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

want to get a list from the dictionary below that contains the third number of each value from each key. For the dictionary below, the desired output would be [400,100,10]. This is as far as I've gotten. My output so far just gives me the three integers like so:
400
100
10
 but it won't let me add the numbers to a single list.

```
my_dict={1:[(20,30,400)],2:[(80,90,100),(8,9,10)]}

for values in my_dict.values():
    for v in values:
        last_num = v[2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just append them to a list:

```
result = []
for values in my_dict.values():
    for v in values:
        last_num = v[2]
        result.append(last_num)
```

You can compress that into a list comprehension:

```
result = [v[2] for values in my_dict.values() for v in values]
```

Note that a dictionary has *no ordering*, so the numbers can come out in different a order depending on the insertion and deletion history of the dictionary.

If you wanted to impose an order (say, by sorted key) you have to do some sorting first:

```
result = [v[2] for k in sorted(my_dict) for v in my_dict[k]]
```

Comment: thanks! Also, do you have any tips as to how I could create a tuple that contained the the lowest number as well as the key it was originally paired with? For ex: (2,10) would be the output here.

Comment: You can use the `min()` function for that: `min(((k, v[2]) for k in my_dict for v in my_dict[k]), key=lambda i: i[1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line

```
[ x[2] for l in my_dict.values() for x in l ]
```

For

```
my_dict={1:[(20,30,400)],2:[(80,90,100),(8,9,10)]}
```

This returns

```
[400, 100, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks, but only get [100,200] in the output, and the 300 is left out.

Comment: Awesome. I found a way to sum the values corresponding to the same key. For example, if I were to create a dictionary, it would look something like          {1:400, 2:110}. However, whenever I try to print this result, it comes out as two separate dictionaries  {1:400} and on the next line {2:110}. I was wondering if you knew of a way to just create one single dictionary with these particular keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

As Martjin said just append them to a list. Using a -1 to add the last value of any length list / tuple

```
list_of_values = []
for lists in my_dict.values():
for tuple in lists:
    list_of_values.append(tuple[-1])
```